# Tensor invariants constructed from identity tensor

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

It is evident that tensors constructed from copies of the identity tensor (and scalars) eg 
$t^{ij}_{kl} = 2 \delta^i_k \delta^j_l - \delta^i_l \delta^j_k$
are invariant under any matrix group, and are closed under addition (of tensors of the same type), tensor multiplication and trace.
Is there a generally accepted name for these tensors?

Comment: You may want to either add some more details about what you actually mean by a tensor, or add some more tags. In the context of just the given tags, I cannot make sense of the question.

Comment: By a tensor of type (r,s) over a finite-dimensional vector space V I mean an element of $T^r_s = \hom(V^{\otimes s},V^{\otimes r}$, where $V^{\otimes r}$ denotes the tensor product of $r$ copies of $V$, representable with respect to a basis of $V$ by an array $t^{i_1...i_r}_{j_1...j_s}$. The tensors I am speaking about are of balanced type $(n,n)$, and can be considered as the image of the group algebra $k(S_n)$ under the natural map $k(S_n) \to T^n_n$.